# jQuery mobile: Dynamically add image

Tags: php, json, jquery-mobile, dynamic, page-init

I am trying to load a static street view image, where the various parameters are stored in a mysql database. After trying lots of alternatives, I'm now passing the database data to a javascript variable and then trying to build the relevant URL (taking into account the page width along the way).

The page loads as restaurant.php?r=xyz where xyz is looked up on MySQL to return a line of data $r that is passed into a javascript array. Some of the array fields are used to create the URL of a Google Street view static image, which should then be loaded into the page.

This works fine if I enter the get to this page having started elsewhere on the site (or after a page refresh).

But if I start from this page and navigate around all future links to restaurant.php?r=abc do not load the image (it is downloaded and can be seen in the Chrome sources box). The pageinit event fires but the .html() fails to change the content (but reports no error).

I suspect I am breaking several laws of javascript, and jquery mobile....

Declared in header

```
var resto = {};

 function insertSVPhoto() {
        console.log("insertSVPhoto: Loaded data for: "+resto['rname']);
        if ( Math.round(resto['heading']) != 0) {
            var width = Math.round( $(document).width() * .9);
            var s= "x250&location="+resto['lat']+",%20"+resto['lng']+"&fov=60&heading="+resto['heading']+"&pitch="+resto['pitch']+"&sensor=false";
            var photo = "<img src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size="+width+s+"'>";
            console.log("Loading photo: "+photo);
            $('#svphoto').html(photo);
        } else { 
            console.log('No photo available');
            $('#svphoto').html("<img src=''>");
        }
    }
```

And then below I have

```
<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true">
<script type="text/javascript" >
<?php
    echo "resto = ".json_encode($r).";"; 
?>
$( document ).on("pageinit", insertSVPhoto );
</script>
    <div id='svphoto'></div>
```

Comment: Try binding it to `pagebeforeshow`.

Comment: No, didn't help. I've also tried using `.attr('src', ...)` to change the photo directly, and it only works reliably when restaurant.php has been loaded by jqm/ajax rather than loaded directly (or after a page refresh)

Answer (score 0):

I have to confess i'm no expert here but the way you're doing this doesn't seem quite right to me, i'd do the following:

```
   window.onload = function () {
   if(! window.device)
     deviceReady()
    }

    document.addEventListener("deviceReady", deviceReady, false);

    function deviceReady() {
     $(document).delegate('#YOUR_PAGE_ID', 'pageshow', function () {

      // Add your stuff here for doing the photo....
    }
```

Again I only started using JQM a while ago but I know this works for an app i've done(and for a phonegap build too!)

EDIT: Also I would seriously consider putting everything all in one HTML document the way you've developed this is going to cause you a massive nose bleed if you try and build this as a mobile app, JQM is not designed to be used in the same way as Jquery, all of your "pages" should exist in one single html document and then use the navigation functions to move between pages.

Thanks

Marc

Answer (score 0):

add data-ajax="false" or rel="external" to your links.. that should make it load properly

```
<a href="hello" data-ajax="false">hello</a>
```

OR

```
<a href="hello" rel="external">hello</a>
```